# Linux and Active Directory - No such file or directory

Tags: linux, authentication, active-directory, home-directory

My Linux box has the "CREATE_HOME" directive set to yes under /etc/login.defs

This box is joined to Active Directory and AD users are allowed to connect.

But when trying to connect with an AD account (ADTest) I get the following:

```
ssh ADTest@my-server
Password:
Could not chdir to home directory /home/ADTest: No such file or directory
-bash-4.1$
```

What do I need to do to ensure that if the home directory of an AD user doesn't exist it gets created?

PS: I want the home directory to be created in the server and not mapped to the server from any other location.

Thanks